# Can I set Memcached object lifetime to less than 1 second?

Tags: caching, memcached

I'm implementing long polling application, which will ask database every 0.2 seconds if there are new messages. When there is many clients connected, they all will be doing unnecessary queries to database which could be cached in shared memory for short time ~0.2s.
Is it possible with Memcached? If not, what is another approach to improve efficency of such application?

Comment: A typical and easy way is a lockfile - `fstat()` it and react on existance and last midification time

Comment: I would have dozens of concurrent connections trying to open same file at the same time. I don't think it's the best solution - the file might get corrupted.

Comment: The CONTENT of the file is of no importance - the existance and modification timestamp count: The event producer touches the file, the event consumer runs fstat() (not fopen()!) on it

Comment: Won't that fstat() be a bottleneck when it will be checked for example 1000x per second from different processes?